# set API limit with paw

Tags: api, get, strapi, paw-app

The headless CMS we using only sends a `100` responses unless you set the limit to `-1` and then it returns everything.

is there a way to set API `get` call with paw (or even postman)? I see that I can add headers, body and set the options but I don't see how I can set `limit`.

Sorry I'm new to API calls and trying to learn but have hit a wall with this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get your `url` and add `?_limit=30` to the ending of it. That example will set the limit to 30. If you set it to `-1` it will pull everything.

Link Strapi documentation:
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/content-api.html#limit

I believe `?_limit=[input your desired number]` is a universal thing.

In `paw` if you type `?` after your `url` it will open `URL Params` and you can enter `limit` in there.